# Stack overflow error in java concerning inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, stack-overflow

I am working on a project for my intro to java class and am working on inheritance.  The problem is with the classes `Mammal` and `Pet`.  When I run the driver class I get a stack overflow error on line 12 where it calls `setName(inName)`  of `Mammal`.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
package inlab9;


/**
 * Driver for Inlab9.
 * 
 * @author yaw 
 * @version 14 Nov 2014
 */
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pet p = new Pet("Terrance");
        p.printInfo();
        System.out.println();
    
        Mammal m = new Mammal();
        m.printInfo();
        m.setName("Roxie");
        m.printInfo();
        System.out.println();
    
        Fish f = new Fish("red");
        f.printInfo();
        f.setName("Shark");
        f.printInfo();
        System.out.println();
    
        Dog d = new Dog("Watson", "Basset");
        d.printInfo();
    }
}
```

```
package inlab9;

public class Mammal extends Pet {
    protected static String name = "Fluffy";

    public Mammal(){
        super(name);
    }

    public void setName(String inName){
        setName(inName);
    }
    public void printInfo(){
        System.out.println("The pet's name is " +name);
    }
}
```

```
package inlab9;

public class Pet {
    protected String name;

    public Pet(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void printInfo(){
        System.out.println("The pets name is " + name);
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: The implementation of `setName()` looks a little problematic.

Comment: Aside from the answers, there are some conceptual problem with your inheritance tree. By making `Pet` a superclass of `Mammal` for instance, you are saying that a mammal is a pet. There are tons of mammals that can't be domesticated. Also, some `Fish` can be pets. Therefore, it is probably best to make `Pet` an interface instead of a class. Remember, the scope narrows when you get down the inheritance tree. That means that a subclass is a more specific type than its superclass.  This rule is not observed in your example. I know it has nothing to do with your problem, but a needed observation.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here,in class Mammal

```
public void setName(String inName){
    setName(inName);//<-- recursive class
}
```

Try instead, if you really want to override it, else don't do it

```
@Override
public void setName(String inName){
    super.setName(inName);
}
```

Comment: perfect I didn't think t use super.setName.  Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

To call the super class method, you should write:

```
public void setName(String inName){
    super.setName(inName);
}
```

That said, you don't really need to implement `setName` in the sub-class if it only calls the super class implementation.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
public void setName(String inName){
   setName(inName);
}
```

you are recursively calling the method and there is no break to stop it, so the stack keeps incrementing until it overflows. You might want to try using the keyword `super` before to call the parent class' method:

`super.setName(inName);`

But since this is a child of a parent with this predefined method, you really don't even need this unless you want this method to do something different. That is the point of inheritance.